Calculate Diffie-hellman key agreement using Curve25519 keys using the JCA
I'm generating two Curve25519 keypairs in Java 21 using the following code:
var kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("X25519");
var paramSpec = new NamedParameterSpec("X25519");
kpg.initialize(paramSpec);
var keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

Now I'd like to calculate the key agreement(or shared secret) for the two key pairs using Ed25519:
var keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
keyAgreement.doPhase(publicKey, true);
var result = keyAgreement.generateSecret();

This obviously doesn't work as KeyAgreement only takes a KeyPair made up by a ECPublicKey and ECPrivateKey, not a XECPublicKey and XECPrivateKey.
So what I need to do is convert the XECPublicKey into an ECPublicKey and the XECPrivateKey in an ECPrivateKey.
If I understand correctly, I can take the U point(encoded as a 32 bytes big endian big integer) of the XECPublicKey and compute the compressed affine y coordinate for the ECPublicKey with the following formula:
y = (u-1)/(u+1)

Which I would then need to decompress using the twisted Edwards point decompression algorithm(is it already implemented in Java?). Then from there I don't know how to get the affine x coordinate. Both should be 48 bytes long.
While for the private key, I'd have to compute the S coordinate(encoded as a 48 bytes long big endian Big integer) from the scalar component of the XECPrivateKey. I don't really know how to though.

The Java doc of XECPrivateKey mentions that there is also a special XDHKeyAgreement https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/security/interfaces/XECPrivateKey.html Based on the source code algorithm name seems to be XDH instead of ECDH.

You don't mean Ed25519; that's a signature algorithm (only) and not a keyagreement algorithm at all. But you could also just look at the standard-names documentation and note that X25519 is defined in 7748 and is not compatible with the standards for ECDH, X9.63 and 3278, which support only Weierstrass curves, which are the ones represented by EC{Private,Public}Key with no X or Ed in front.

Did you mean JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) instead of JCA (Java Connector Architecture)?

@MarkRotteveel no I mean the Java cryptographic architecture

@dave_thompson_085 https://github.com/signalapp/curve25519-java/blob/70fae57d6dccff7e78a46203c534314b07dfdd98/common/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/curve25519/Curve25519.java#L72 Here it calls it an ECDH agreement though

@Auties01 Ugh, thanks, I had missed that they had renamed JCE to JCA and in the process introduced a duplicate abbreviation in the Java landscape...
